# Filter list of dictionaries with specific keys present in final list

Tags: python, dictionary, projection

I have list of dictionaries, for example:

```
my_dict = [
    {"name": "Al", "age": 10, "id": 1},
    {"name": "Bert", "age": 15, "id": 2},
    {"name": "Charles", "age": 17, "id": 3}
]
```

I need resultant list of dictionary containing only `'name'` and `'id'` keys.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: You can't just coin a term without a full explanation and expect a meaningful answer. That being said, the answer is dictionary comprehension figures in the answer.

Comment: `Me need dictionary` how many? One? All? What is a projection?

Comment: If you need a one-liner, here it is `print [{"name":i["name"], "id":i["id"]} for i in d]` where d is the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You may do it with below combination of *list comprehension* and *dict comprehension* expression as:

```
my_dict_list = [
     {"name": "Al", "age": 10, "id": 1},
     {"name": "Bert", "age": 15, "id": 2},
     {"name": "Charles", "age": 17, "id": 3}
]

# Set of keys you want to filter in new list
new_keys = {"id", "name"}

new_dict_list = [{k: d.get(k) for k in new_keys} for d in my_dict_list]
#                       ^ To fill the value as `None` if key not present
#                         in any intermediate dict
```

where `new_dict_list` will hold the value:

```
>>> new_dict_list
[
     {'name': 'Al', 'id': 1}, 
     {'name': 'Bert', 'id': 2}, 
     {'name': 'Charles', 'id': 3}
]
```

Comment: so so tremendous, thank you)

Comment: `new_keys` is better expressed as a set for faster membership checking: `new_keys = {"id", "name"}`

Comment: @AKX Huh? It's not used for membership checking.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Oops, my bad. Misread the code.